# Creating a SQL statement based on a column enum value

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, architecture, enums

Let's assume I have a table called normalize with an enum column called type

Depending on the row (Let's assume the types are a, b or c) I want to do a LEFT JOIN based on whatever the type is.

So, if type = a, LEFT JOIN ON table a .. if type = B, LEFT JOIN ON table b... etc

Can this be done efficiently? Or should this be done at the application layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM parent
    LEFT JOIN a ON (type = 'a' AND parent.id = a.id)
    LEFT JOIN b ON (type = 'b' AND parent.id = b.id)
    LEFT JOIN c ON (type = 'c' AND parent.id = c.id)
```

You may or may not need an index on `type`, depending on the actual data and how smart your DBMS is (in exploiting indexes that ought to exist underneath PKs). In any case, **measure** on realistic amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

One common approach is to store the type as a 1:1 relation.  In this approach, there is no type enum column.  The fact that an ID is present in a 1:1 extension table indicates its type.

```
select  *
from    BaseTable b
left join
        Type1Table t1
on      t1.Id = b.Id
left join
        Type1Table t2
on      t2.Id = b.Id
```

So an entity with an entry in `b` and `t1` must be of type 1.  An entity with an entry in `b` and in `t2` is of type 2.  That way, the information is only stored once, and an inconsistency where the table would say "type 1" but there was no matching row in `t1` is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that even if you use `SELECT table1.* FROM table1 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2`, the engine will evaluate the join even though you don't even need to show them.

So, in my opinion there are 2 options:

- 1st: Assume the joins are effective, using proper indexes and with an acceptable I/O, and use the following query:

** SEE BELOW, WITHIN THE LIST IT BUGS **

- Assume doing n joins, n being the number of different type (if there's a table per type), would give to much overhead, and then procede at the applicative layer with 2 queries: the first to get the type and then another within a switch case statement for example to retrieve datas from the right table.

Explain plan also could give you a good clue of what you're doing

Query:

```
SELECT
    IF(t.type = a, ta.value,
        IF(type = b, tb.value, IF(type = c, tc.value, td.value))
    )
FROM 
    table t
        LEFT JOIN type_a_table ta ON t.type = a AND ...
        LEFT JOIN type_a_table tb ON t.type = b AND ...
        LEFT JOIN type_a_table tc ON t.type = c AND ...
        LEFT JOIN type_a_table td ON t.type = d AND ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I would probably use a union to perform what you're looking for

```
select * 
from BaseTable b left join TypeTableA a on b.id = a.id
union
select * 
from BaseTable b left join TypeTableB b on b.id = b.id
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work in case `TypeTableA` and `TypeTableB` have different columns (which is probably the whole point). Also you have a syntax error: you use the same alias (`b`) for two different tables.